# When echo multiple file data it only display last file info

Tags: codeigniter

On my multiple upload library I have a function which is called upload data.

And another function called upload.

For some reason when I select multiple images and is success full when I use on my controller

```
$data = $this->multiple_upload->upload_data();

echo $data['file_name'];
```

It will only get the name of the last file selected it does not return all file names selected. It should display all file names selected.

**Question:** How on my library `function upload_data()` can I make sure can return data correctly rather than just the last one. the upload_data function just seems to only return the last file information.

Library

```
<?php

class Multiple_upload {

    public function __construct($config = array()) {

        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        $this->files = $this->clean($_FILES);

        empty($config) OR $this->set_config($config);

    }

    public function set_config($config) {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function upload($field = 'userfile') {
        if (empty($this->upload_path)) {
            $this->set_error('upload_path_not_set');
            return FALSE;
        } 

        if (!realpath(FCPATH . $this->upload_path)) {
            $this->set_error('upload_path_in_correct');
            return FALSE;
        } 

        if (!empty($this->files[$field]['name'][0])) {

            $check_error = 0;

            foreach ($this->files[$field]['name'] as $key => $value) {

                $this->file_name = $this->files[$field]['name'][$key];
                $this->file_temp = $this->files[$field]['tmp_name'][$key];
                $this->file_size = $this->files[$field]['size'][$key];
                $this->get_file_extension = explode('.', $this->files[$field]['name'][$key]);
                $this->get_file_extension_end = strtolower(end($this->get_file_extension));

                if (!in_array($this->get_file_extension_end, $this->allowed_types)) {

                    $this->set_error('file_extension_not_allowed');

                    $check_error++;
                } 

                if ($this->files[$field]['size'][$key] > $this->max_size) {

                    $this->set_error('file_size_check');

                    $check_error++;
                }

                if ( ! @copy($this->file_temp, FCPATH . $this->upload_path . '/' . $this->file_name)) {

                    if ( ! @move_uploaded_file($this->file_temp, FCPATH . $this->upload_path . '/' . $this->file_name)) {

                        $this->set_error('upload_destination_error', 'error');

                        $check_error++;
                    }

                }

            }

            if($check_error > 0 ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            // This lets me get file data in another function
            return $this;

        }
    }

    public function upload_data() {

        $data = array(
            'file_name' => $this->file_name,
            'file_path' => FCPATH . $this->upload_path . '/'
        );

        return $data;
    }

    public function set_error($message) {

        $this->CI->lang->load('upload', 'english');

        $msg = "";

        if ($message == 'upload_path_not_set') {

            $msg .= $this->CI->lang->line($message);
        }

        if ($message == 'upload_path_in_correct') {

            $msg .= $this->CI->lang->line($message);
        }

        if ($message == 'file_extension_not_allowed') {

            $msg .= sprintf($this->CI->lang->line($message), $this->file_name, $this->get_file_extension_end);

        }

        if ($message == 'file_size_check') {

            $msg .= sprintf($this->CI->lang->line($message), $this->file_name, $this->max_size);

        }

        return $this->error_message[] = $msg;
    }

    public function display_error_messages($open_tag = '<p>', $close_tag = '</p>') {

        $message = "";

        if (isset($this->error_message)) {

            foreach($this->error_message as $msg) {
                $message .= $open_tag . $msg . $close_tag;
            }


        }

        return $message;

    }

    public function clean($data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                unset($data[$key]);

                $data[$this->clean($key)] = $this->clean($value);
            }
        } else {
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
public function upload_data() {

    $data[] = array(
        'file_name' => $this->file_name,
        'file_path' => FCPATH . $this->upload_path . '/'
    );

    return $data;
}
```

**Controller index function**

```
public function index(){

    $data['error'] = '';

    $this->load->library('multiple_upload');

    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = array('jpg', 'png');
    $config['max_size'] = 3000000;
    //$config['max_size'] = 1000;
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

    $this->multiple_upload->set_config($config);

    if ($this->multiple_upload->upload() == FALSE) {

        $data['error'] = $this->multiple_upload->display_error_messages('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');

        $this->load->view('upload', $data);

    } else {

        $data = $this->multiple_upload->upload_data();

        echo $data['file_name'];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class Multiple_upload {
    private $filenames;
    public function __construct($config = array()) {

        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        $this->files = $this->clean($_FILES);
        $this->filenames = array();
        empty($config) OR $this->set_config($config);

    }

    public function set_config($config) {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function upload($field = 'userfile') {
        if (empty($this->upload_path)) {
            $this->set_error('upload_path_not_set');
            return FALSE;
        } 

        if (!realpath(FCPATH . $this->upload_path)) {
            $this->set_error('upload_path_in_correct');
            return FALSE;
        } 

        if (!empty($this->files[$field]['name'][0])) {

            $check_error = 0;

            foreach ($this->files[$field]['name'] as $key => $value) {

                $this->file_name = $this->files[$field]['name'][$key];
                $this->filenames[]   = $this->files[$field]['name'][$key];
                $this->file_temp = $this->files[$field]['tmp_name'][$key];
                $this->file_size = $this->files[$field]['size'][$key];
                $this->get_file_extension = explode('.', $this->files[$field]['name'][$key]);
                $this->get_file_extension_end = strtolower(end($this->get_file_extension));

                if (!in_array($this->get_file_extension_end, $this->allowed_types)) {

                    $this->set_error('file_extension_not_allowed');

                    $check_error++;
                } 

                if ($this->files[$field]['size'][$key] > $this->max_size) {

                    $this->set_error('file_size_check');

                    $check_error++;
                }

                if ( ! @copy($this->file_temp, FCPATH . $this->upload_path . '/' . $this->file_name)) {

                    if ( ! @move_uploaded_file($this->file_temp, FCPATH . $this->upload_path . '/' . $this->file_name)) {

                        $this->set_error('upload_destination_error', 'error');

                        $check_error++;
                    }

                }

            }

            if($check_error > 0 ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            // This lets me get file data in another function
            return $this;

        }
    }

    public function upload_data() 
    {
        $data = array();
        foreach($this->filenames as $filename)
        {
            $data[] = array(
                'file_name' => $filename,
                'file_path' => FCPATH . $this->upload_path . '/'
            );
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function set_error($message) {

        $this->CI->lang->load('upload', 'english');

        $msg = "";

        if ($message == 'upload_path_not_set') {

            $msg .= $this->CI->lang->line($message);
        }

        if ($message == 'upload_path_in_correct') {

            $msg .= $this->CI->lang->line($message);
        }

        if ($message == 'file_extension_not_allowed') {

            $msg .= sprintf($this->CI->lang->line($message), $this->file_name, $this->get_file_extension_end);

        }

        if ($message == 'file_size_check') {

            $msg .= sprintf($this->CI->lang->line($message), $this->file_name, $this->max_size);

        }

        return $this->error_message[] = $msg;
    }

    public function display_error_messages($open_tag = '<p>', $close_tag = '</p>') {

        $message = "";

        if (isset($this->error_message)) {

            foreach($this->error_message as $msg) {
                $message .= $open_tag . $msg . $close_tag;
            }


        }

        return $message;

    }

    public function clean($data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                unset($data[$key]);

                $data[$this->clean($key)] = $this->clean($value);
            }
        } else {
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

And

```
public function index()
{

    $data['error'] = '';
    $this->load->library('multiple_upload');
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = array('jpg', 'png');
    $config['max_size'] = 3000000;
    //$config['max_size'] = 1000;
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

    $this->multiple_upload->set_config($config);
    if ($this->multiple_upload->upload() == FALSE) 
    {
        $data['error'] = $this->multiple_upload->display_error_messages('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
        $this->load->view('upload', $data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $data = $this->multiple_upload->upload_data();
        foreach($data as $file)
        {
            echo $file['file_name']."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still only displays last image file name selected.

Comment: Wait i am giving you proper solution

Comment: @wolfgang1983 try now and let me know

Comment: Will check in morning.

Comment: Is there any way for doing it for all data instead of just one

Comment: What was the output ??

Answer (score 0):

you can use array to save all files information in upload_data function.

```
public function upload_data() {

        $data = array(
            'file_name' => $this->file_name,
            'file_path' => FCPATH . $this->upload_path . '/'
        );

        return $data;
    }
```

to

```
public function upload_data() {

        $data[] = array(
            'file_name' => $this->file_name,
            'file_path' => FCPATH . $this->upload_path . '/'
        );

        return $data;
    }
```

it will return array of all the file details

Comment: When I do that it now throws error Undefined index: file_name

Comment: you will get response in an array just use this print_r($data). You will need to use loop to get data for each individual file name... or simply use $data[0]['file_name'],$data[1]['file_name'].... so on